# Should new stack exchange sites reflect what has been voted on in the definition phase?

Tags: discussion, area-51

Is it appropriate to totally change the definition of a site already in the private beta phase?  What sense does it make to go through the definition phase in area51, when in the private beta the same questions that are voted 20-0 as on-topic are voted down and closed? Doesn't this make the whole proposal phase a waste of time and superfluous?

Some modification will occur over time, but how radical and after how much time should they be done?

Comment: Do you have any evidence?

Comment: Very similar to the question I had, ChrisF. Is this theoretical or does the questioner have a specific example in mind? At the moment it looks a bit vague.

Comment: Yes. It happened today in the newest private beta site

Answer (score 1):

The definition of the site should not be changed much once the site reaches commitment -- otherwise, people could be "committing" to something different than what they originally committed to!

Do you have an actual example of this happening?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say that we're actually an example of this today on the Food & Cooking beta, but several of us had to fight tooth and nail to keep recipe requests off the site, and there are still several lingering health questions that much of the community didn't seem to agree should be closed.  I think *most* of the beta sites are going to attract a few cranks who either didn't participate in the definition phase or don't understand how the whole process works, and will want to remake the site in their own image.

Comment: Yes it happens on the Theoretical Computing site. I asked first questions to ease in that were very easy to answer, which were immediately closed with the comment, that one could google the answer. Since I thought my questions were in scope that I read from the definition phase, I copied and pasted questions from the definition phase and the question was closed within minutes. When I commented that it was a question from the definition phase, the response was that the definition phase was irrelevant.

Comment: If such things happens, and closed questions do not count for the fulfilment quota, there should be some way to be resolved from the commitment if such fundamental changes are forced.